# Error in Success callbackId ... ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $http

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth, inappbrowser, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a hybrid mobile app with ionic (angular). For this app, I am making an oAuth call which is jQuery dependent so have both libraries loaded, as well as the script for the oAuth and my and my app.

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The call to initiate the authentication is done in the ionic ready event in app.js as shown below:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
  oAuthProcess.authorize({
    client_id: 'client',
    client_secret: 'secret',
    scope: 'scope',
    redirect_uri: 'fake url'
  }).done(function(data){
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data.refresh_token);
    var accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    alert(accessToken);
  }).fail(function(data){alert(data.error);});
});
```

The oAuthProcess function is in the auth.js file which looks like below. It opens the inAppBrowser to perform the authentication and should then close it returning the access token to the app to allow calling APIs:

```
var oAuthProcess = {
  authorize: function(options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var authUrl = 'some url' + $.param({
    client_id: options.client_id,
    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: options.scope
  });
  //Open inAppBrowser with authUrl
  var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
  authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    var url = '' + e.url + '';
    //Upon opening in                   
    var code = url.match(/\?code=(.+)$/);
    var error = url.match(/\?error=(.+)$/);
    if (code != null || error != null) {
      authWindow.close();
    }
    if (code) {
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'some url',
        data: {code: code[1], client_id: options.client_id, client_secret: options.client_secret, redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri, grant_type: 'authorization_code'}
      }).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function(data){
        deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
      });
    } else if (error) {
      deferred.reject({
        error: error[1]
      });
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

};

The app is able to load the inAppBrowser and create a token, however the following error is given which stops the token from getting back to the app after the inAppBrowser is closed.

2015-01-09 16:48:04.299 myApp[2146:483400] Error in Success callbackId: InAppBrowser85303841 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $http

Any help is resolving this or an alternative approach will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$http` is not something that is exposed on the global object. You would need to use dependency injection to access it. Incase you are doing this in the global context you would need to get access to `$http` from `$injector`.

Comment: @PSL thanks for the quick response. Can you please explain abit further, how I can do this? I am very new to angular

Comment: You can get http instance by doing `var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http')` provided you have angular loaded. Also i dont understand what is point of returning a promise from an anonymous event handler.

Comment: @PSL I inherited the auth.js code and not well advance in js enough to re-write or create it myself. How best can such a thing be achieved?

Comment: Add that line of code to the first line of your auth.js file

Answer (score 2):

I'll just type it here so I can show you the code example rather than comment...

Assuming the example you gave is your entire auth.js file, add that example PSL gave you, so the file now looks like this:

```
var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
var oAuthProcess = {
  authorize: function(options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var authUrl = 'some url' + $.param({
    client_id: options.client_id,
    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: options.scope
  });
  //Open inAppBrowser with authUrl
  var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
  authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
    var url = '' + e.url + '';
    //Upon opening in                   
    var code = url.match(/\?code=(.+)$/);
    var error = url.match(/\?error=(.+)$/);
    if (code != null || error != null) {
      authWindow.close();
    }
    if (code) {
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'some url',
        data: {code: code[1], client_id: options.client_id, client_secret: options.client_secret, redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri, grant_type: 'authorization_code'}
      }).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }).error(function(data){
        deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
      });
    } else if (error) {
      deferred.reject({
        error: error[1]
      });
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise();
}
```